# Using: set_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE in .tcl script fails - Quartus

Tags: environment-variables, tcl, quartus

Title says it all really.

I have a setup that requires the use of environment variables when setting these kind of assignments. Most seem to work, but when it comes to QIP_FILE assignments in a tcl script, Quartus errors.
Using an explicit path in the .qsf project file works. Is there any way of using environment variables in a .qsf file, or am I doing something wrong in my .tcl script?

The line I am using is:

```
set_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE $::env(MY_VAR_PATH)/my/path/my.qip
```

Any help on this would be great,

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The error I get when attempting to use the .tcl script is:

```
------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Can't open project: flash_leds

    while executing
"project_open $project_name -cmp $ap_name"
    (file "/opt/altera/15.0/quartus/common/tcl/internal/qsh_smart.tcl" line 60)
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Probably depends on the content of MY_VAR_PATH. If its a single absolute path, try `file normalize $::env(MY_VAR_PATH)/my/path/my.qip` which might help tidy up the path.

Comment: It's also _possible_ that the code really wants a relative path when used that way. Hope that's not true! What does the error message say exactly?

Comment: Tried what you suggested @patthoyts, and same issue. Just added the error as an edit. It complains that it can't open the project...

Comment: It doesn't appear to expand the variables there. I just created a test file with this statement in and in the quartus tcl console executed 'get_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE` and it has returned '$::env(MY_VAR_PATH)/my.qip'.

Answer (score 2):

So I managed to find a solution!

I was calling this .tcl script as *source* in the .qsf file (as it included other scripts which also needed sourcing. Turns out, for some reason, that the

```
set_global_assignment -name QIP_FILE ...
```

command doesn't work when the .tcl file is called using source (but other set_global_assignment calls do work... I don't really know whats happening there!).

To solve this I had to create another .tcl file and move all of the set_global_assignment calls to there, leaving the other file with only the other *sourced* scripts. This new file then has to be included in the .qsf file in the following way:

```
set_global_assignment -name SOURCE_TCL_SCRIPT_FILE <filename>
```

This seemed to solve my issue, and the QIP file was correctly found using the environment variable path.

Comment: Firstly, I'm happy it's working for you. Secondly, W! T! F! I can think of a few ways to make code work like that, and every last one of them is strangely bizarre…

Comment: I don't disagree... It's just the world I'm stuck in unfortunately!